# How do I plot mixed-effects linear regression?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, boxplot, lme4

I'm trying to make a boxplot to visualize this regression model

```
library(lme4)
lmer(dv1 ~ intervention + (1|id/area),
            data=data,
            REML=T)
```

In this experiment, the control and treatment intervention are both applied to a subject within discrete areas.

Here's the data I'm using

```
data <- data.frame("id" = 1:2, 
           "intervention" = c(rep("a",27),rep("b", 27)),
           "area" = 1:3,
           "dv1" = rnorm(54),
           "dv2" = rnorm(54),
           "dv3" = rnorm(54))
data$area <- as.factor(data$area)
data$id <- as.factor(data$id)
```

Here's what I've tried

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x=area,y=dv1,col=intervention)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.2) + 
  facet_wrap(~id) + 
  ggtitle("DV1") +
  xlab("Intervention") +
  ylab("DV1")
```

[image]

Instead of the red points overlaying the red boxplot, they're all over the place. How do I fix this?

Edit: I used the jitter options that u/eipi10 suggested and this is what I have now.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=area,y=dv1,col=intervention)) +
  geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.75, jitter.height=0, jitter.width=0.25), alpha=0.6) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.2, size=0.3) + 
  facet_wrap(~id) + 
  ggtitle("DV1") +
  xlab("Area") +
  ylab("DV1")
```

[image]

Comment: I answered your original question, but it looks like you've changed the plot code/plot. I'll delete my answer in a few minutes, as it no longer applies. If you want the points to go with the appropriate boxplot, do `geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.75))`. If you also want the points dodged, use `position_jitterdodge`.

Comment: @eipi10 I thought it more appropriate to plot the effect of intervention within area within subject. Thanks for the help!